# SQL to combine and show total

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Good afternoon,

I've been trying to create a small table which totals up some numbers in relation to an industry.

What I need to do is combine multiple rows into one. The number values represent the amount of projects within each industry, The two tables connect via the `Expense Cat ID` in sub-selects.

Example sub-query:

```
 ,(SELECT COUNT (*) FROM [projects]
  left join [territory]
  on projects.territoryid = territory.territoryid
  WHERE expense_category.expensecategoryid = projects.expense_category
  AND projects.status = 'Live'
  ) AS [Live Projects]
```

so what I'm trying to achieve is the combination of rows  where the name of the expense category is identical then combine the rows.

In a nutshell:

```
CREATE view [dbo].[Industry_Projects_figures] as
WITH [top25_industries] as (
SELECT expense_cat
   ,(Select COUNT(projectid) from project_table
where project = live) as [Live projects]
   ,(Select COUNT(projectid) from project_table
where project = live) as [Cancelled Projects]
   ,(Select COUNT(projectid) from project_table
where project = live) as [Completed]
From industry_table
GROUP BY expense_cat
)
select TOP 25 [top25_industries].*,
   [Live Projects] + [Cancelled]  + [Completed]  as [Grand Total]
   FROM [top25_industries]
   ORDER BY [Grand Total] DESC
```

Ends up producing:

```
Industry:
Utilities & Energy    19  143   117   451       
Utilities & Energy   172   69    98   339           
Utilities & Energy    43   21    23    87
```

Each row of represents the parent and two child sub-industries! So I need to combine them :(

Comment: Your SQL should only produce an error, because you cannot put the SELECT keyword twice (`SELECT TOP 1000 SELECT...`)

Comment: Yup it will error, I just wrote that up as a example!

Comment: Examples that work are verifiable. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out today!

What I was doing wrong was my second select, I should have been GROUPing by the expense_cat, you can see from my code above I was SELECTING * from the temp table, I simply select'd the Expense Cat and grouped by it. Now the table is looking a lot better.

Also I had expense cats where the names were similar but not the same, E.G Other - Bacon, Other - Baconz, Other - MOAR Bacons).

All I needed to do is setup a CASE WHEN clause in my first select to filter any expense_cats where the name was  LIKE 'other%' THEN 'Other' which enables my second select to group them all together! :)

Answer (score 0):

Select sum(cancelled) over (partition by expense_cat) 
           + sum(completed) over (partition by expense_cat) 
       from top25_industries

If expense_Cat column is the 'Utilities & Energy' column, it should sum up the cancelled and completed totals for each industry.

Comment: Hi Shilpa,Isn't that the same as doing a GROUP BY ROLLUP?